# Assign incremental labels to a vector in R

Tags: r

What is the most efficient way to assign incremental labels to groups in R?

```
test_vec <- c('a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a')
```

intended result:

```
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3
```

I know you can do this with the rle function but I am trying to avoid nested for-loops, because the actual dataset is large.

Comment: Perhaps `data.table::rleid(test_vec)`

Comment: `test_vec <- c('a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a');
r <- rle(test_vec);
r$values <- 1:length(r$values);
inverse.rle(r)`

Comment: @akrun YES, and I should delete my comment.

Comment: Or using `base R` with `==` `cumsum(c(TRUE, test_vec[-1] != test_vec[-length(test_vec)]))`